# simple question my data is not displaying when being called by handlebars helpers

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am trying to display a user's name by calling it using handlebars helpers below is the handlebar page in question.

```
<div class="profile">
    <div class="profile-header">
       {{user.name}}
    {{#if portfolio.length}}
        {{#each portfolio as |portfolio|}}
            <div class="profile-port">
                {{> port-info portfolio}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn profile-btn"><a href="/profile/edit/{{portfolio.id}}"> Edit Info</a></button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn profile-btn">View Profile</button>
            </div>
        {{/each}}

        {{else}}
        <h4>No user information added.</h4>
        <button type="submit" class="btn profile-btn"><a href="/profile/create"> Create Portfolio</a></button>

    {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```

below is the user model that should be called to the page.

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');

class User extends Model {
  checkPassword(loginPw) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(loginPw, this.password);
  }
}

User.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      github: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          isEmail: true,
        },
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          len: [8],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCreate: async (newUserData) => {
          newUserData.password = await bcrypt.hash(newUserData.password, 10);
          return newUserData;
        },
        beforeUpdate: async (updatedUserData) => {
          updatedUserData.password = await bcrypt.hash(updatedUserData.password, 10);
          return updatedUserData;
        },
      },
      sequelize,
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true,
      underscored: true,
      modelName: 'user',
    }
  );
  
  module.exports = User;
```

when logged in the else case for the handlebar code will work but will not display the user's name. I have dropped the database to reload a fresh user with it and still will not pull anything.

Comment: I am guessing that your `user` object is not what you think it is. Try `{{log user}}` and see what gets logged so that you know what object you are dealing with.